# python - ImportError while installing ftfy package

Tags: python, package

ImportError when installing ftfy in python. 
please help me to resolve this.
Thanks

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
```

ImportError: No module named extern

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pkg-resources
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/529217/not-able-to-fix-the-error-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-pack

Comment: That solved my problem...